# Codeigniter: Complex query for 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, join

I have 2 tables:

```
events     event_follows
-------    -------------
id         id
title      user_id
content    event_id
user_id
```

I need get all events for certain user_id, count of events, get all events which was followed by this user and get all events and count of followed. Really, I have no idea how do this correctly in 1 query.

Comment: `$this->db->get_where('event_follows', array('used_id' => $user_id));` and then you head on to `$this->db->get_where('events', array('user_id' => $user_id);` and then parse it

Comment: Your Expected O/P plzz??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've make some solution. But unfortunately it is more complex then 1 query:

```
    // Fetch all events which was joined by user
    $this->db->select('event_id')
             ->from('event_follows')
             ->where('user_id', $id);

    $query1 = $this->db->get(); 
    $result = $query1->result_array();   

    // Drop keys
    $joined_events = array();       
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        array_push($joined_events, $row["event_id"]);   
    }

    // Fetch all events
    $this->db->select('events.*, COUNT(event_follows.id) as followers')
             ->from('events')
             ->where('events.user_id', $id)
             ->or_where_in('events.id', $joined_events);
    $this->db->join('event_follows', 'event_follows.event_id = events.id', 'left')
             ->group_by('event_follows.event_id');

    $query2 = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I could understand from your question, I can only think of this solution:

```
$query = "select e.*, count(e.*), ef.*, count(ef.*) from events e join event_follows ef on ef.user_id = e.user_id where e.user_id = '$my_id' ";
$data['info'] = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

//Then, you can use php's echo "<pre>", print_r() and die() functions 
//to test the result:

echo "<pre>";
print_r(data['info']);
die();
```